# Getting rid of the gradient at the top of an Activity (Android)

Tags: android, user-interface

How can I get rid of the gradient at the top of my screen (the very top of the blue in the screenshot below... below the notification bar)?

[simple screenshot http://dl.dropbox.com/u/299320/device.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/299320/device.png)

Comment: Screenshot is down

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is themable; look at the `windowContentOverlay` attribute. In particular, you can create a new [theme](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html):

```
<style name="Theme.Foo" parent="android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And then declare that your activity should use this theme:

```
<activity android:name=".FooActivity"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.Foo"> ...
```

Although a better option is to set this theme for all activities in the application, for consistency:

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.Foo"> ...
```