# Remove default drop shadow at top of activity layout?

Tags: android

I have an activity. It does not have a title bar. The content view is just a linear layout. It looks like android draws a drop shadow at the top of my content view, directly below the status bar. Is there a way to stop that from being drawn?

My layout is just:

```
<LinearLayout ... />
```

I have no titlebar:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Thanks.

Comment: This has [already been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931953).

Answer (score 28):

In res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Then in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" 
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Custom" >
...
</activity>
```

Answer (score 4):

In res/values/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Custom" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```