# Removing the shadow which comes below a tab layout in android. [done]

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am curious to know if there is anyway I can remove OR change the **drop-shadow** like effect that android gives below a Tab layout.

[image: shadow_below_tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as I ask this question, I get the answer in another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931953/getting-rid-of-the-gradient-at-the-top-of-an-activity-android). Anyways for the benefit of people who have landed on this post, the answer is to 
use a custom theme with its **windowContentOverlay** set to **null**

Comment: <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null<item/>  not working for me on Android lollipop versions