# Android Unable to remove the color at the top and bottom

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, tablet, shadow

[image]I have added a scrollView and if deploy on the android tablet,it has some problems. But it works fine on cellphone.

When users move to the top or bottom of the whole page,it will automatically show the blue shadow which indicates users reaching the bottom of the page. 
I want to remove those indicator since it affects the UI.

Is there any way to remove or set in the XML?

I have tried different parameter to set on the scrollview but it doesn't work.

Please help.

Comment: Update:this problem not only happen on tablet,it also appears in the ICS (3.0+)

Answer (score 64):

fadingEdge is deprecated. Use this in your ScrollView:
 `android:overScrollMode="never"`

Answer (score 14):

Add this extra line to your ScrollView definition:

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

or add this to your code:

```
findViewById(R.id.sobreScrollView).setOverScrollMode(ScrollView.OVER_SCROLL_NEV‌​ER);
```

Comment: Thats really helpful!! Can you please tell me , Is it possible to change the color of the respective default scrollView blue color

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Answer (score 7):

Add this to the scrollView

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

Comment: I have tried this method and it doesn't work.
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:background="@null"
android:cacheColorHint="@null"

Comment: Is it just remove the edge of the border instead of the top or bottom of that page?

Comment: I have added to scrollview or linearlayout inside the scrollview but it doesn't work either. I wonder if there is any solution.

Comment: now it is depricated: http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/R.attr.html#fadingEdge

Answer (score 3):

Pre API level 14:

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

API level 14+:

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="none"
```

See this:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fadingEdge

> This attribute is deprecated and will be ignored as of API level 14 (ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH). Using fading edges may introduce noticeable performance degradations and should be used only when required by the application's visual design. To request fading edges with API level 14 and above, use the android:requiresFadingEdge attribute instead.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about API level 14+, I needed that.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [Romain Piel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334209/romain-piel) on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7106752/956975, [Pim Reijersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/655302/pim-reijersen) pointed out in the comments that `android:fadingEdge` is deprecated and will be ignored as of API level 14.

Remove the shadow on a `ListView`/`GridView`/`ScrollView` like so

in XML:

```
android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
```

in Java:

```
view.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER)