# Overscroll scrolling indicators with clip to padding

Tags: android, listview, clip, overscroll

Im having this problem I cant get rid of on froyo and gingerbread.
I am using clipToPadding="false" attribute to not have the top and bottom padding around listView unless its ends. However on 2.2 and 2.3 this with the clipToPadding, causes the overscroll indicator or how should I call it, to ignore my clipToPadding setting and makes those white lines appear on my images not the screen edges.

[image]

This is however not present on ICS

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106692/remove-shadow-from-top-and-bottom-of-listview-in-android)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe those white lines you're seeing are the `fadingEdge` of the `ListView`.  You can get rid of them by adding this attribute to your `ListView` in xml:

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

or in code:

```
listview.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
```

In ICS and forward, fading edges are disabled by default which is why you don't see them.