# Setting the shadow on android's TabLayout

Tags: android, android-xml, android-tablayout

I want to remove the shadow below TabLayout. I Tried setting this feature as a theme, but it doesn't work:

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null<item/>
```

Or

```
<item name="windowContentOverlay">@null<item/>
```

I was wandering if there's another way to do this, from the XML declaration or from code behind on the TabLayout instance.

I'm aware of this solution, which doesn't work for me.
[Getting rid of the gradient at the top of an Activity (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931953/getting-rid-of-the-gradient-at-the-top-of-an-activity-android)
Please, **don't suggest the theme fix**, I know it's the best android-way to go here, but it's not an option for me.

This is my XML declaration :

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tab_on_state"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_off_state" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Shadow is not cast by the TabLayout but the container in which it resides.
If you are using TabLayout in ActionBar then set the background of ActionBar to solid colour to remove the shadow. 
I have tried it on ActionBar but i guess it should work fine for other pattern like AppBarLayout

Comment: Hi, I'm not using an actionbar, it's in one of the layouts.

Comment: This is the only right answer among a lot of similar answers around the web. It seems that the container is causing the shadow and not the TabLayout. I just set the android:elevation to 0 in the TabLayout container.