# Remove the shadow below TabLayout on android

Tags: android, android-styles, android-tablayout

I'm trying to remove the shadow below tabs while using TabLayout, which is defined in a normal layout (and not as a part of a toolbar or actionbar).

Setting theme as

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null<item/>
```

or

```
<item name="windowContentOverlay">@null<item/>
```

didn't work.

Also, setting elevation to 0 didn't help either.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
```

Comment: check out this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931953/getting-rid-of-the-gradient-at-the-top-of-an-activity-android)

Comment: are you serious ? that's exactly what i said i did..

Comment: Ok, But I tried your code and I am not getting any shadow In API 21 (Lolipop) can you tell me on which API you are testing your app and elevation works on API level 21 or higher

Comment: Yes on Android L i am facing same problem and its not action bar shadow, its tablayout shadow. and    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null<item/>   not working for me too..

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm assuming your `TabLayout` is inside `AppBarLayout`, that shadow comes with `AppBarLayout`, add this `app:elevation="0dp"` to that widget and I believe you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks. **`app:elevation="0dp"`** helped me to remove shadow below `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` (encapsulated in `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`). So in consequence there is no shadow above TabLayout.

Answer (score 8):

I try `app:elevation="0dp"` work and `android:elevation="0dp"` does not work
in `AppBarLayout`

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the elevation to 0dp and I also change the theme of `AppBarLayout` to `@style/Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout` and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

on your activity write this

```
supportActionBar?.elevation = 0f
```

Comment: The OP has already mentioned that it is not using any `actionBar`, so this line will not execute in first place.

Answer (score -2):

Put `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);` in MainActivity java file like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```